openDatabaseAsync and non-std C++ exception - Expo
my project use Expo , i wanted to use sqlite database , i followed this documentation , after instalation of dependency , i created a new file Database.js , and added this two lines
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const db = await SQLite.openDatabaseAsync('myDatabase');

then run the app , and its crashed with the following screen  , iven afteer adding the code to create table and crud operation still the same error , its coming from the second line


I got the same issue, but no solution yet.
